# Data lookup from multiple tables at once

Tags: sql-server

I have four tables.
R (r_key, r_id)
T (t_key, t_id) 
RT (r_key, t_key, isA, _co, _cb)
and
RT_Imp (r_id, t_id, isA, _co, _cb).

I need to copy data from RT_Imp to RT. I need to copy data only for r_id which is already there in R. If r_id is not there in R, it's data should not be copied.

While copying I need to fetch r_key and t_key from R and T respectively matching with r_id and t_id.

I have tried

```
INSERT INTO RT
SELECT R.R_key, T.T_key, RT_Imp.isA, RT_Imp._co, RT_Imp._cb
FROM R, T, RT_Imp
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT *  
FROM R, T, RT_Imp
WHERE R.R_id = RT_Imp.R_id
and T.T_id = RT_Imp.T_id
and RT_Imp.R_id = R.R_id
)
```

But its giving me all rows repeated.
What should be my query to execute this?

Comment: In your outer query (before the WHERE EXISTS), you need to co-relate all your tables the same way you do in the EXISTS clause.   Otherwise you get a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO rt
SELECT 
    rkey.r_key,
    tkey.t_key,
    new.isA,
    new._co,
    new._cb
FROM @RT_Imp new
INNER JOIN @R rkey
    ON rkey.r_id = new.r_id
INNER JOIN @T tkey
    ON tkey.t_id = new.t_id
LEFT JOIN @RT old
    ON old.r_key = rkey.r_key
WHERE old.r_key IS NULL
```

Join all the tables, and this will insert all of the rt_imp records not found in rt based on r_key.  You should use a select statement first to see all the data before updating.